# Ordering tennis sessions so that no player plays with anyone again

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there are 16 players who wish to play doubles on 4 courts i.e. 4 matches are played simultaneously. After all players have finished their current match, they change partners and opponents, and start a new round of matches. If each player refuses to play with someone he/she has played with before (either as a partner or opponent), what is the maximum number of rounds that can be played, and what is an efficient/intuitive method of scheduling the matches?

My approach was to label the players A to P, arrange them in a grid:

```
A B C D
E F G H
I J K L
M N O P
```

and take rows: A-B vs C-D, until M-N vs O-P. I could also take columns: A-E vs I-M, until D-H vs L-P. (2 rounds so far)

Shifting the rows:

```
A B C D
F G H E
K L I J
P M N O
```

gave another set of columns: A-F vs K-P, until D-E vs J-O. (3 rounds so far)

Shifting again doesn't work as e.g. A has already played against I:

```
A B C D
G H E F
I J K L
O P M N
```

If we relax the condition such that each player is now willing to play against a former partner, or partner a former opponent, what is the new solution?

More generally, if instead of 16 players on 4 courts, we have 4 *n* players on *n* courts, how is the solution changed?

Comment: It is easily shown that there can be only one round for n < 4. E.g. if n = 3, in the 2nd round, everyone who played on the first court must play on a different court (to not meet one another again) but there are only 3 courts to fit these 4 players.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the original problem you mentioned (each pair appears on the same court at most once):

Here's a reworking of your shift algorithm that gives a different perspective on where things go wrong.  To each player we associate a point $(x,y)$ where $0 \leq x,y \leq 3$.  Each set of matches in your construction then can be thought of as pairing players together based on a value of a certain linear function.

- Set 1: Players are assigned a court based on the value of $x$.
- Set 2: Players are assigned a court based on the value of $y$
- Set 3 (shift $1$): Players are assigned a court based on the value of $y-x \mod 4$.
- Set 4 (shift $2$): Players are assigned a court based on the value of $y-2x \mod 4$
- Set 5 (shift $3$): Players are assigned a court based on the value of $y-3x \mod 4$.

Ignore the first set of matches for a moment.  Then the remaining four sets all have the form "Players are assigned based off of $y-kx$" (set $2$ corresponds to $k=0$).  We want to make sure that players are never together more than once.  This corresponds to saying "knowing $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$, there's never more than $1$ value of $k$ that puts them together. Given the two points, we should be able to determine $k$". In other words, we should always be able to solve the equation
$$y_1-kx_1=y_2-kx_2$$
for $k$.

This is a linear equation in $k$, and what we'd like to do is solve it the way we would any other linear equation, getting 
$$k=\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}.$$
The trouble is that we're working modulo $4$, and we can't always divide by $x_1-x_2$ even when $x_1-x_2 \neq 0$.  So in some cases we may have more than one solution for $k$, corresponding to two people meeting more than once (e.g. the example you mentioned where $(0,0)$ and $(0,2)$ are together for both $k=0$ and $k=2$).

The way to fix this is to replace your "mod $4$" grid by a grid where we actually can divide.  Do the same construction as before, but now replace $\{0,1,2,3\}$ by $\{0,1,a,b\}$, the four elements of a [Finite Field of Order $4$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=finite%20field%20of%20order%204) (both in the coordinates $x$ and $y$ and in the definition of the sets themselves.  So one of the sets of matches will involve putting people together that share a common value of $x-ay$).

Mathematically, the object we're constructing in this fashion is known as a **Finite Affine Plane.**

Answer (score 1):

There can be at most 5 rounds for 16 players on 4 courts, e.g.

```
1. A-B vs C-D, E-F vs G-H, I-J vs K-L, M-N vs O-P
2. A-E vs I-M, B-F vs J-N, C-G vs K-O, D-H vs L-P
3. A-F vs K-P, B-E vs L-O, C-H vs I-N, D-G vs J-M
4. A-G vs L-N, B-H vs K-M, C-E vs J-P, D-F vs I-O
5. A-H vs J-O, B-G vs I-P, C-F vs L-M, D-E vs K-N
```

as brute-forced by this very ugly C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // for printf
#include <string.h> // for memset

#define N 16
#define P(x,y) played[N * (y) + (x)]
char *names = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
char played[N * N];

int plot() {
 char X, Y;
 printf("\t ");
 for (X = 0; X < N; ++X) { printf(" %c", names[X]); }
 printf("\n");
 for (Y = 0; Y < N; ++Y) {
  printf("\t%c", names[Y]);
  for (X = 0; X < N; ++X) {
   switch (P(X,Y)) {
    case  0: printf(" ."); break;
    case ~0: printf(" X"); break;
    default: printf(" %d", P(X,Y));
   }
  }
  printf("\n");
 }
}

int main() {
 char z,y,x,w,v,u,t,s,r,q,p,o,n,m,l,k;
 char count = 0;
 memset(&played, 0, sizeof(played));
 for (x = 0; x < N; ++x) { P(x,x) = ~0; }
 for (z = 0; z < 1; ++z) {                                                                                                                                   // printf("z=%d\n",z);
 for (y = 0; y < N; ++y) { if (y==z                                                                                     || P(y,z)                ) continue; // printf(" y=%d\n",y);
 for (x = 0; x < N; ++x) { if (x==z||x==y                                                                               || P(x,z)||P(x,y)        ) continue; // printf("  x=%d\n",x);
 for (w = 0; w < N; ++w) { if (w==z||w==y||w==x                                                                         || P(w,z)||P(w,y)||P(w,x)) continue; // printf("   w=%d\n",w);
 for (v = 0; v < N; ++v) { if (v==z||v==y||v==x||v==w                                                                                            ) continue; // printf("    v=%d\n",v);
 for (u = 0; u < N; ++u) { if (u==z||u==y||u==x||u==w||u==v                                                             || P(u,v)                ) continue; // printf("     u=%d\n",u);
 for (t = 0; t < N; ++t) { if (t==z||t==y||t==x||t==w||t==v||t==u                                                       || P(t,v)||P(t,u)        ) continue; // printf("      t=%d\n",t);
 for (s = 0; s < N; ++s) { if (s==z||s==y||s==x||s==w||s==v||s==u||s==t                                                 || P(s,v)||P(s,u)||P(s,t)) continue; // printf("       s=%d\n",s);
 for (r = 0; r < N; ++r) { if (r==z||r==y||r==x||r==w||r==v||r==u||r==t||r==s                                                                    ) continue; // printf("        r=%d\n",r);
 for (q = 0; q < N; ++q) { if (q==z||q==y||q==x||q==w||q==v||q==u||q==t||q==s||q==r                                     || P(q,r)                ) continue; // printf("         q=%d\n",q);
 for (p = 0; p < N; ++p) { if (p==z||p==y||p==x||p==w||p==v||p==u||p==t||p==s||p==r||p==q                               || P(p,r)||P(p,q)        ) continue; // printf("          p=%d\n",p);
 for (o = 0; o < N; ++o) { if (o==z||o==y||o==x||o==w||o==v||o==u||o==t||o==s||o==r||o==q||o==p                         || P(o,r)||P(o,q)||P(o,p)) continue; // printf("           o=%d\n",o);
 for (n = 0; n < N; ++n) { if (n==z||n==y||n==x||n==w||n==v||n==u||n==t||n==s||n==r||n==q||n==p||n==o                                            ) continue; // printf("            n=%d\n",n);
 for (m = 0; m < N; ++m) { if (m==z||m==y||m==x||m==w||m==v||m==u||m==t||m==s||m==r||m==q||m==p||m==o||m==n             || P(m,n)                ) continue; // printf("             m=%d\n",m);
 for (l = 0; l < N; ++l) { if (l==z||l==y||l==x||l==w||l==v||l==u||l==t||l==s||l==r||l==q||l==p||l==o||l==n||l==m       || P(l,n)||P(l,m)        ) continue; // printf("              l=%d\n",l);
 for (k = 0; k < N; ++k) { if (k==z||k==y||k==x||k==w||k==v||k==u||k==t||k==s||k==r||k==q||k==p||k==o||k==n||k==m||k==l || P(k,n)||P(k,m)||P(k,l)) continue; // printf("               k=%d\n",k);
  P(z,y) = P(z,x) = P(z,w) = P(y,x) = P(y,w) = P(x,w) =    P(y,z) = P(x,z) = P(w,z) = P(x,y) = P(w,y) = P(w,x) =
  P(v,u) = P(v,t) = P(v,s) = P(u,t) = P(u,s) = P(t,s) =    P(u,v) = P(t,v) = P(s,v) = P(t,u) = P(s,u) = P(s,t) =
  P(r,q) = P(r,p) = P(r,o) = P(q,p) = P(q,o) = P(p,o) =    P(q,r) = P(p,r) = P(o,r) = P(p,q) = P(o,q) = P(o,p) =
  P(n,m) = P(n,l) = P(n,k) = P(m,l) = P(m,k) = P(l,k) =    P(m,n) = P(l,n) = P(k,n) = P(l,m) = P(k,m) = P(k,l) =
   ++count;
  printf("\n%2d: %c-%c vs %c-%c, %c-%c vs %c-%c, %c-%c vs %c-%c, %c-%c vs %c-%c\n\n", count,
         names[z], names[y], names[x], names[w],    names[v], names[u], names[t], names[s],
         names[r], names[q], names[p], names[o],    names[n], names[m], names[l], names[k]);
  plot();
 } // k
 } // l
 } // m
 } // n
 } // o
 } // p
 } // q
 } // r
 } // s
 } // t
 } // u
 } // v
 } // w
 } // x
 } // y
 } // z
 return 0;
}
```

which gave the following result. The plots show who has already played with whom. Rows and columns are players, and a number at each intersection denotes the round that they played each other. The main diagonal is crossed out because a player cannot play with himself/herself.

```
 1: A-B vs C-D, E-F vs G-H, I-J vs K-L, M-N vs O-P

          A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P
        A X 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . . .
        B 1 X 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . . .
        C 1 1 X 1 . . . . . . . . . . . .
        D 1 1 1 X . . . . . . . . . . . .
        E . . . . X 1 1 1 . . . . . . . .
        F . . . . 1 X 1 1 . . . . . . . .
        G . . . . 1 1 X 1 . . . . . . . .
        H . . . . 1 1 1 X . . . . . . . .
        I . . . . . . . . X 1 1 1 . . . .
        J . . . . . . . . 1 X 1 1 . . . .
        K . . . . . . . . 1 1 X 1 . . . .
        L . . . . . . . . 1 1 1 X . . . .
        M . . . . . . . . . . . . X 1 1 1
        N . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 X 1 1
        O . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 X 1
        P . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 1 X

 2: A-E vs I-M, B-F vs J-N, C-G vs K-O, D-H vs L-P

          A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P
        A X 1 1 1 2 . . . 2 . . . 2 . . .
        B 1 X 1 1 . 2 . . . 2 . . . 2 . .
        C 1 1 X 1 . . 2 . . . 2 . . . 2 .
        D 1 1 1 X . . . 2 . . . 2 . . . 2
        E 2 . . . X 1 1 1 2 . . . 2 . . .
        F . 2 . . 1 X 1 1 . 2 . . . 2 . .
        G . . 2 . 1 1 X 1 . . 2 . . . 2 .
        H . . . 2 1 1 1 X . . . 2 . . . 2
        I 2 . . . 2 . . . X 1 1 1 2 . . .
        J . 2 . . . 2 . . 1 X 1 1 . 2 . .
        K . . 2 . . . 2 . 1 1 X 1 . . 2 .
        L . . . 2 . . . 2 1 1 1 X . . . 2
        M 2 . . . 2 . . . 2 . . . X 1 1 1
        N . 2 . . . 2 . . . 2 . . 1 X 1 1
        O . . 2 . . . 2 . . . 2 . 1 1 X 1
        P . . . 2 . . . 2 . . . 2 1 1 1 X

 3: A-F vs K-P, B-E vs L-O, C-H vs I-N, D-G vs J-M

          A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P
        A X 1 1 1 2 3 . . 2 . 3 . 2 . . 3
        B 1 X 1 1 3 2 . . . 2 . 3 . 2 3 .
        C 1 1 X 1 . . 2 3 3 . 2 . . 3 2 .
        D 1 1 1 X . . 3 2 . 3 . 2 3 . . 2
        E 2 3 . . X 1 1 1 2 . . 3 2 . 3 .
        F 3 2 . . 1 X 1 1 . 2 3 . . 2 . 3
        G . . 2 3 1 1 X 1 . 3 2 . 3 . 2 .
        H . . 3 2 1 1 1 X 3 . . 2 . 3 . 2
        I 2 . 3 . 2 . . 3 X 1 1 1 2 3 . .
        J . 2 . 3 . 2 3 . 1 X 1 1 3 2 . .
        K 3 . 2 . . 3 2 . 1 1 X 1 . . 2 3
        L . 3 . 2 3 . . 2 1 1 1 X . . 3 2
        M 2 . . 3 2 . 3 . 2 3 . . X 1 1 1
        N . 2 3 . . 2 . 3 3 2 . . 1 X 1 1
        O . 3 2 . 3 . 2 . . . 2 3 1 1 X 1
        P 3 . . 2 . 3 . 2 . . 3 2 1 1 1 X

 4: A-G vs L-N, B-H vs K-M, C-E vs J-P, D-F vs I-O

          A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P
        A X 1 1 1 2 3 4 . 2 . 3 4 2 4 . 3
        B 1 X 1 1 3 2 . 4 . 2 4 3 4 2 3 .
        C 1 1 X 1 4 . 2 3 3 4 2 . . 3 2 4
        D 1 1 1 X . 4 3 2 4 3 . 2 3 . 4 2
        E 2 3 4 . X 1 1 1 2 4 . 3 2 . 3 4
        F 3 2 . 4 1 X 1 1 4 2 3 . . 2 4 3
        G 4 . 2 3 1 1 X 1 . 3 2 4 3 4 2 .
        H . 4 3 2 1 1 1 X 3 . 4 2 4 3 . 2
        I 2 . 3 4 2 4 . 3 X 1 1 1 2 3 4 .
        J . 2 4 3 4 2 3 . 1 X 1 1 3 2 . 4
        K 3 4 2 . . 3 2 4 1 1 X 1 4 . 2 3
        L 4 3 . 2 3 . 4 2 1 1 1 X . 4 3 2
        M 2 4 . 3 2 . 3 4 2 3 4 . X 1 1 1
        N 4 2 3 . . 2 4 3 3 2 . 4 1 X 1 1
        O . 3 2 4 3 4 2 . 4 . 2 3 1 1 X 1
        P 3 . 4 2 4 3 . 2 . 4 3 2 1 1 1 X

 5: A-H vs J-O, B-G vs I-P, C-F vs L-M, D-E vs K-N

          A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P
        A X 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 2 5 3 4 2 4 5 3
        B 1 X 1 1 3 2 5 4 5 2 4 3 4 2 3 5
        C 1 1 X 1 4 5 2 3 3 4 2 5 5 3 2 4
        D 1 1 1 X 5 4 3 2 4 3 5 2 3 5 4 2
        E 2 3 4 5 X 1 1 1 2 4 5 3 2 5 3 4
        F 3 2 5 4 1 X 1 1 4 2 3 5 5 2 4 3
        G 4 5 2 3 1 1 X 1 5 3 2 4 3 4 2 5
        H 5 4 3 2 1 1 1 X 3 5 4 2 4 3 5 2
        I 2 5 3 4 2 4 5 3 X 1 1 1 2 3 4 5
        J 5 2 4 3 4 2 3 5 1 X 1 1 3 2 5 4
        K 3 4 2 5 5 3 2 4 1 1 X 1 4 5 2 3
        L 4 3 5 2 3 5 4 2 1 1 1 X 5 4 3 2
        M 2 4 5 3 2 5 3 4 2 3 4 5 X 1 1 1
        N 4 2 3 5 5 2 4 3 3 2 5 4 1 X 1 1
        O 5 3 2 4 3 4 2 5 4 5 2 3 1 1 X 1
        P 3 5 4 2 4 3 5 2 5 4 3 2 1 1 1 X
```

Comment: Seems like that's actually $5$ rounds instead of $4$ (you left out the initial $1,2$ vs. $3,4$. etc.).  I think this should be identical to the finite field construction I gave in my answer (there's essentially only one $4 \times 4$ affine plane).

Comment: Thanks, I should've scrolled up :O) I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As for "If we relax the condition such that each player is now willing to play against a former partner, or partner a former opponent, what is the new solution?" the answer is still 5, as above, as output by this brute-force program:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // for printf
#include <string.h> // for memset

#define N 16
#define P(x,y)  partner[N * (y) + (x)]
#define O(x,y)  oppose [N * (y) + (x)]
#define P2(x,y) P(x,y) = P(y,x)
#define O2(x,y) O(x,y) = O(y,x)

int main() {
 char z,y,x,w,v,u,t,s,r,q,p,o,n,m,l,k, i;
 char count = 0;
 char *names = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
 char partner[N * N], oppose[N * N];
 memset(&partner, 0, sizeof(partner));
 memset(&oppose,  0, sizeof(oppose ));
 for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) { P(i,i) = O(i,i) = ~0; } // cannot play oneself
 for (z = 0; z < 1; ++z) {                                                                                                                                                             // printf("z=%d\n",z);
 for (y = 0; y < N; ++y) { if (y==z                                                                                     || P(y,z)                 || O(y,z)                ) continue; // printf(" y=%d\n",y);
 for (x = 0; x < N; ++x) { if (x==z||x==y                                                                               || P(x,z)||P(x,y)         || O(x,z)||O(x,y)        ) continue; // printf("  x=%d\n",x);
 for (w = 0; w < N; ++w) { if (w==z||w==y||w==x                                                                         || P(w,z)||P(w,y)||P(w,x) || O(w,z)||O(w,y)||O(w,x)) continue; // printf("   w=%d\n",w);
 for (v = 0; v < N; ++v) { if (v==z||v==y||v==x||v==w                                                                                                                      ) continue; // printf("    v=%d\n",v);
 for (u = 0; u < N; ++u) { if (u==z||u==y||u==x||u==w||u==v                                                             || P(u,v)                 || O(u,v)                ) continue; // printf("     u=%d\n",u);
 for (t = 0; t < N; ++t) { if (t==z||t==y||t==x||t==w||t==v||t==u                                                       || P(t,v)||P(t,u)         || O(t,v)||O(t,u)        ) continue; // printf("      t=%d\n",t);
 for (s = 0; s < N; ++s) { if (s==z||s==y||s==x||s==w||s==v||s==u||s==t                                                 || P(s,v)||P(s,u)||P(s,t) || O(s,v)||O(s,u)||O(s,t)) continue; // printf("       s=%d\n",s);
 for (r = 0; r < N; ++r) { if (r==z||r==y||r==x||r==w||r==v||r==u||r==t||r==s                                                                                              ) continue; // printf("        r=%d\n",r);
 for (q = 0; q < N; ++q) { if (q==z||q==y||q==x||q==w||q==v||q==u||q==t||q==s||q==r                                     || P(q,r)                 || O(q,r)                ) continue; // printf("         q=%d\n",q);
 for (p = 0; p < N; ++p) { if (p==z||p==y||p==x||p==w||p==v||p==u||p==t||p==s||p==r||p==q                               || P(p,r)||P(p,q)         || O(p,r)||O(p,q)        ) continue; // printf("          p=%d\n",p);
 for (o = 0; o < N; ++o) { if (o==z||o==y||o==x||o==w||o==v||o==u||o==t||o==s||o==r||o==q||o==p                         || P(o,r)||P(o,q)||P(o,p) || O(o,r)||O(o,q)||O(o,p)) continue; // printf("           o=%d\n",o);
 for (n = 0; n < N; ++n) { if (n==z||n==y||n==x||n==w||n==v||n==u||n==t||n==s||n==r||n==q||n==p||n==o                                                                      ) continue; // printf("            n=%d\n",n);
 for (m = 0; m < N; ++m) { if (m==z||m==y||m==x||m==w||m==v||m==u||m==t||m==s||m==r||m==q||m==p||m==o||m==n             || P(m,n)                 || O(m,n)                ) continue; // printf("             m=%d\n",m);
 for (l = 0; l < N; ++l) { if (l==z||l==y||l==x||l==w||l==v||l==u||l==t||l==s||l==r||l==q||l==p||l==o||l==n||l==m       || P(l,n)||P(l,m)         || O(l,n)||O(l,m)        ) continue; // printf("              l=%d\n",l);
 for (k = 0; k < N; ++k) { if (k==z||k==y||k==x||k==w||k==v||k==u||k==t||k==s||k==r||k==q||k==p||k==o||k==n||k==m||k==l || P(k,n)||P(k,m)||P(k,l) || O(k,n)||O(k,m)||O(k,l)) continue; // printf("               k=%d\n",k);
  // z-y vs x-w, v-u vs t-s, r-q vs p-o, n-m vs l-k
  P2(z,y)=P2(x,w)                 = P2(v,u)=P2(t,s)                 = P2(r,q)=P2(p,o)                 = P2(n,m)=P2(l,k)                 =
  O2(z,x)=O2(z,w)=O2(y,x)=O2(y,w) = O2(v,t)=O2(v,s)=O2(u,t)=O2(u,s) = O2(r,p)=O2(r,o)=O2(q,p)=O2(q,o) = O2(n,l)=O2(n,k)=O2(m,l)=O2(m,k) =
   ++count;
  printf("\n%2d: %c-%c vs %c-%c, %c-%c vs %c-%c, %c-%c vs %c-%c, %c-%c vs %c-%c\n\n", count,
         names[z], names[y], names[x], names[w],    names[v], names[u], names[t], names[s],
         names[r], names[q], names[p], names[o],    names[n], names[m], names[l], names[k]);
    { // Plot
     char X, Y;
     printf("\tp"); for (X = 0; X < N; ++X) { printf(" %c", names[X]); }
     printf("\to"); for (X = 0; X < N; ++X) { printf(" %c", names[X]); }
     printf("\n");
     for (Y = 0; Y < N; ++Y) {
      printf("\t%c", names[Y]);
      for (X = 0; X < N; ++X) {
       switch (P(X,Y)) {
        case  0: printf(" ."); break;
        case ~0: printf(" X"); break;
        default: printf(" %d", P(X,Y));
       }
      }
      printf("\t%c", names[Y]);
      for (X = 0; X < N; ++X) {
       switch (O(X,Y)) {
        case  0: printf(" ."); break;
        case ~0: printf(" X"); break;
        default: printf(" %d", O(X,Y));
       }
      }
      printf("\n");
     }
    }
 } // k
 } // l
 } // m
 } // n
 } // o
 } // p
 } // q
 } // r
 } // s
 } // t
 } // u
 } // v
 } // w
 } // x
 } // y
 } // z
 return 0;
}
```

The left plot shows partnerships and the right, players who have played as opponents:

```
1: A-B vs C-D, E-F vs G-H, I-J vs K-L, M-N vs O-P

       p A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P       o A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P
       A X 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . .       A X . 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . . .
       B 1 X . . . . . . . . . . . . . .       B . X 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . . .
       C . . X 1 . . . . . . . . . . . .       C 1 1 X . . . . . . . . . . . . .
       D . . 1 X . . . . . . . . . . . .       D 1 1 . X . . . . . . . . . . . .
       E . . . . X 1 . . . . . . . . . .       E . . . . X . 1 1 . . . . . . . .
       F . . . . 1 X . . . . . . . . . .       F . . . . . X 1 1 . . . . . . . .
       G . . . . . . X 1 . . . . . . . .       G . . . . 1 1 X . . . . . . . . .
       H . . . . . . 1 X . . . . . . . .       H . . . . 1 1 . X . . . . . . . .
       I . . . . . . . . X 1 . . . . . .       I . . . . . . . . X . 1 1 . . . .
       J . . . . . . . . 1 X . . . . . .       J . . . . . . . . . X 1 1 . . . .
       K . . . . . . . . . . X 1 . . . .       K . . . . . . . . 1 1 X . . . . .
       L . . . . . . . . . . 1 X . . . .       L . . . . . . . . 1 1 . X . . . .
       M . . . . . . . . . . . . X 1 . .       M . . . . . . . . . . . . X . 1 1
       N . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 X . .       N . . . . . . . . . . . . . X 1 1
       O . . . . . . . . . . . . . . X 1       O . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 X .
       P . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 X       P . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 . X

2: A-E vs I-M, B-F vs J-N, C-G vs K-O, D-H vs L-P

       p A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P       o A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P
       A X 1 . . 2 . . . . . . . . . . .       A X . 1 1 . . . . 2 . . . 2 . . .
       B 1 X . . . 2 . . . . . . . . . .       B . X 1 1 . . . . . 2 . . . 2 . .
       C . . X 1 . . 2 . . . . . . . . .       C 1 1 X . . . . . . . 2 . . . 2 .
       D . . 1 X . . . 2 . . . . . . . .       D 1 1 . X . . . . . . . 2 . . . 2
       E 2 . . . X 1 . . . . . . . . . .       E . . . . X . 1 1 2 . . . 2 . . .
       F . 2 . . 1 X . . . . . . . . . .       F . . . . . X 1 1 . 2 . . . 2 . .
       G . . 2 . . . X 1 . . . . . . . .       G . . . . 1 1 X . . . 2 . . . 2 .
       H . . . 2 . . 1 X . . . . . . . .       H . . . . 1 1 . X . . . 2 . . . 2
       I . . . . . . . . X 1 . . 2 . . .       I 2 . . . 2 . . . X . 1 1 . . . .
       J . . . . . . . . 1 X . . . 2 . .       J . 2 . . . 2 . . . X 1 1 . . . .
       K . . . . . . . . . . X 1 . . 2 .       K . . 2 . . . 2 . 1 1 X . . . . .
       L . . . . . . . . . . 1 X . . . 2       L . . . 2 . . . 2 1 1 . X . . . .
       M . . . . . . . . 2 . . . X 1 . .       M 2 . . . 2 . . . . . . . X . 1 1
       N . . . . . . . . . 2 . . 1 X . .       N . 2 . . . 2 . . . . . . . X 1 1
       O . . . . . . . . . . 2 . . . X 1       O . . 2 . . . 2 . . . . . 1 1 X .
       P . . . . . . . . . . . 2 . . 1 X       P . . . 2 . . . 2 . . . . 1 1 . X

3: A-F vs K-P, B-E vs L-O, C-H vs I-N, D-G vs J-M

       p A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P       o A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P
       A X 1 . . 2 3 . . . . . . . . . .       A X . 1 1 . . . . 2 . 3 . 2 . . 3
       B 1 X . . 3 2 . . . . . . . . . .       B . X 1 1 . . . . . 2 . 3 . 2 3 .
       C . . X 1 . . 2 3 . . . . . . . .       C 1 1 X . . . . . 3 . 2 . . 3 2 .
       D . . 1 X . . 3 2 . . . . . . . .       D 1 1 . X . . . . . 3 . 2 3 . . 2
       E 2 3 . . X 1 . . . . . . . . . .       E . . . . X . 1 1 2 . . 3 2 . 3 .
       F 3 2 . . 1 X . . . . . . . . . .       F . . . . . X 1 1 . 2 3 . . 2 . 3
       G . . 2 3 . . X 1 . . . . . . . .       G . . . . 1 1 X . . 3 2 . 3 . 2 .
       H . . 3 2 . . 1 X . . . . . . . .       H . . . . 1 1 . X 3 . . 2 . 3 . 2
       I . . . . . . . . X 1 . . 2 3 . .       I 2 . 3 . 2 . . 3 X . 1 1 . . . .
       J . . . . . . . . 1 X . . 3 2 . .       J . 2 . 3 . 2 3 . . X 1 1 . . . .
       K . . . . . . . . . . X 1 . . 2 3       K 3 . 2 . . 3 2 . 1 1 X . . . . .
       L . . . . . . . . . . 1 X . . 3 2       L . 3 . 2 3 . . 2 1 1 . X . . . .
       M . . . . . . . . 2 3 . . X 1 . .       M 2 . . 3 2 . 3 . . . . . X . 1 1
       N . . . . . . . . 3 2 . . 1 X . .       N . 2 3 . . 2 . 3 . . . . . X 1 1
       O . . . . . . . . . . 2 3 . . X 1       O . 3 2 . 3 . 2 . . . . . 1 1 X .
       P . . . . . . . . . . 3 2 . . 1 X       P 3 . . 2 . 3 . 2 . . . . 1 1 . X

4: A-G vs L-N, B-H vs K-M, C-E vs J-P, D-F vs I-O

       p A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P       o A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P
       A X 1 . . 2 3 4 . . . . . . . . .       A X . 1 1 . . . . 2 . 3 4 2 4 . 3
       B 1 X . . 3 2 . 4 . . . . . . . .       B . X 1 1 . . . . . 2 4 3 4 2 3 .
       C . . X 1 4 . 2 3 . . . . . . . .       C 1 1 X . . . . . 3 4 2 . . 3 2 4
       D . . 1 X . 4 3 2 . . . . . . . .       D 1 1 . X . . . . 4 3 . 2 3 . 4 2
       E 2 3 4 . X 1 . . . . . . . . . .       E . . . . X . 1 1 2 4 . 3 2 . 3 4
       F 3 2 . 4 1 X . . . . . . . . . .       F . . . . . X 1 1 4 2 3 . . 2 4 3
       G 4 . 2 3 . . X 1 . . . . . . . .       G . . . . 1 1 X . . 3 2 4 3 4 2 .
       H . 4 3 2 . . 1 X . . . . . . . .       H . . . . 1 1 . X 3 . 4 2 4 3 . 2
       I . . . . . . . . X 1 . . 2 3 4 .       I 2 . 3 4 2 4 . 3 X . 1 1 . . . .
       J . . . . . . . . 1 X . . 3 2 . 4       J . 2 4 3 4 2 3 . . X 1 1 . . . .
       K . . . . . . . . . . X 1 4 . 2 3       K 3 4 2 . . 3 2 4 1 1 X . . . . .
       L . . . . . . . . . . 1 X . 4 3 2       L 4 3 . 2 3 . 4 2 1 1 . X . . . .
       M . . . . . . . . 2 3 4 . X 1 . .       M 2 4 . 3 2 . 3 4 . . . . X . 1 1
       N . . . . . . . . 3 2 . 4 1 X . .       N 4 2 3 . . 2 4 3 . . . . . X 1 1
       O . . . . . . . . 4 . 2 3 . . X 1       O . 3 2 4 3 4 2 . . . . . 1 1 X .
       P . . . . . . . . . 4 3 2 . . 1 X       P 3 . 4 2 4 3 . 2 . . . . 1 1 . X

5: A-H vs J-O, B-G vs I-P, C-F vs L-M, D-E vs K-N

       p A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P       o A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P
       A X 1 . . 2 3 4 5 . . . . . . . .       A X . 1 1 . . . . 2 5 3 4 2 4 5 3
       B 1 X . . 3 2 5 4 . . . . . . . .       B . X 1 1 . . . . 5 2 4 3 4 2 3 5
       C . . X 1 4 5 2 3 . . . . . . . .       C 1 1 X . . . . . 3 4 2 5 5 3 2 4
       D . . 1 X 5 4 3 2 . . . . . . . .       D 1 1 . X . . . . 4 3 5 2 3 5 4 2
       E 2 3 4 5 X 1 . . . . . . . . . .       E . . . . X . 1 1 2 4 5 3 2 5 3 4
       F 3 2 5 4 1 X . . . . . . . . . .       F . . . . . X 1 1 4 2 3 5 5 2 4 3
       G 4 5 2 3 . . X 1 . . . . . . . .       G . . . . 1 1 X . 5 3 2 4 3 4 2 5
       H 5 4 3 2 . . 1 X . . . . . . . .       H . . . . 1 1 . X 3 5 4 2 4 3 5 2
       I . . . . . . . . X 1 . . 2 3 4 5       I 2 5 3 4 2 4 5 3 X . 1 1 . . . .
       J . . . . . . . . 1 X . . 3 2 5 4       J 5 2 4 3 4 2 3 5 . X 1 1 . . . .
       K . . . . . . . . . . X 1 4 5 2 3       K 3 4 2 5 5 3 2 4 1 1 X . . . . .
       L . . . . . . . . . . 1 X 5 4 3 2       L 4 3 5 2 3 5 4 2 1 1 . X . . . .
       M . . . . . . . . 2 3 4 5 X 1 . .       M 2 4 5 3 2 5 3 4 . . . . X . 1 1
       N . . . . . . . . 3 2 5 4 1 X . .       N 4 2 3 5 5 2 4 3 . . . . . X 1 1
       O . . . . . . . . 4 5 2 3 . . X 1       O 5 3 2 4 3 4 2 5 . . . . 1 1 X .
       P . . . . . . . . 5 4 3 2 . . 1 X       P 3 5 4 2 4 3 5 2 . . . . 1 1 . X
```